# How to check if the current user from devise has a certain attribute set

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, devise

For this website I am using **devise** to create user profiles. Some users have special permission attributes. In this case db_admin_status is a Boolean attribute. If the user has this set to True, then I want certain nav-links to appear on the page.

This is what the user model looks like

```
Table name: users
#
#  id                     :bigint           not null, primary key
#  db_admin_status        :boolean
#  email                  :string           default(""), not null
#  encrypted_password     :string           default(""), not null
#  name                   :string
#  remember_created_at    :datetime
#  reset_password_sent_at :datetime
#  reset_password_token   :string
#  user_name              :string
#  created_at             :datetime         not null
#  updated_at             :datetime         not null
```

For this rails project I am using application.html.erb and Bootstrap. So in my collapse-nav bar I have embedded in other if statements (that do work) this:

```
<%if current_user.db_admin_status == 'true'%>
 <!--- links appear on nav bar-->
<%end%>
```

However even when my current user im signed in as has the attribute set to true, the links still don't show up

Comment: You don't need to use any comparisons in a conditional where you're using only 1 boolean variable. Check my answer on how to properly modify your application.html.erb file and db_admin_status field so that for a new user, it defaults to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **Step 1.)**

You don't need to use any comparisons in the conditional statement as a boolean variable will just result to true/false by itself.

Simply doing

```
<% if current_user.db_admin_status %>
  // your code
<% end
```

should suffice.

## **Step 2.)**

You could run into trouble when the value of db_admin_status is nill (has not been set yet). You can fix this by defaulting the field to `false` in your database schema:

Run the following command to create a rails migration to update the db_admin_status field to default to false.

```
rails g migration DefaultDbAdminStatusToFalseOnUser
```

This should create a file `db/migrate/20130201121110_default_db_admin_status_to_false_on_user.rb`

```
class DefaultDbAdminStatusToFalseOnUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    // your changes go here
  end
end
```

Modify this file to update your field on the user table.

```
change_column :users, :db_admin_status, :boolean, :default => false
```

And then finally migrate your changes by running:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to compare your attribute as boolean and not string.

```
current_user.db_admin_status == true
```

Although i would create a helper method which would check if user is eligible to show link and call that method from your view.

```
def should_show_some_link?
  current_user.db_admin_status? #which will return true or false
end
```

Also your column `db_admin_status` is not set to default, is that what you want? When the new user creates the value will be nil and not false.